# local.properties flutter.minSdkVersion=21 but not working

Tags: flutter

This is a newly created project. Nothing had changed, excepted added one line in `pubspecs.yaml`

```
flutter_inappwebview: 5.0.5
```

In order for the above package to work, I need to change the minSdkVersion to higher. So I have edited the `local.properties`, and added 3 lines at the bottom

```
sdk.dir=xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
flutter.sdk=D:\\Flutter\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
flutter.minSdkVersion=21
flutter.targetSdkVersion=30
flutter.compileSdkVersion=30
```

But I am still getting the following error:

```
lib\main.dart:1
xxxx\gbc\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 17 declared in library [:flutter_inappwebview]
xxxx\gbc\build\flutter_inappwebview\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
    or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 17,
    or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is a half-baked solution from Flutter. We need to manually change the following lines in: `android\app\build.gradle`

```
minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()
compileSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.compileSdkVersion').toInteger()
```